# Insert a newline after punctuations

Tags: key-bindings, filetype-tex

I'm writing a report in LaTeX that I keep in a Git repository. In order to make the most out of Git, I would like to keep each sentence on its own line. I.e. for each dot, exclamation mark and question mark - while I'm in insert mode - I would like vim automatically to insert a newline.

However, I only want this to happen in the body of the text and not between `{}`, `[]`, `()`, `""` or `''` because in LaTeX, I may want to write filenames or commands between these characters.

Is there any way I can achieve this with a key mapping in insert mode, or is there another preferred way of doing this?

Comment: You could… simply press `<CR>` when needed.

Comment: @romainl Thank you for your reply. Yes I could simply press Enter but since I'm not used to pressing Enter every type I press `.` I feel that it would be simpler to have vim do it for me. That way, I would not forget it.

Comment: Your question sounds like an  [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/288754) to me. `In order to make the most out of Git, I would like to keep each sentence on its own line.`: I don't see how keeping each sentence on a line help you make the most out of Git. Also `inoremap . .<cr>` will make a press on the dot in insert mode insert a dot and a newline, but it doesn't check for the brackets.

Comment: @statox The OP is talking about [semantic linefeeds](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/one-sentence-per-line/). If you are hard-wrapping lines, it makes viewing (line-based) diffs easier if each sentence starts a new line.

Comment: @statox ...and an alternative solution to that problem is to use soft-wrapped lines and Git's `--word-diff`.

Comment: @Rich: TIL about semantic linefeeds, thanks :)

Comment: By far the easiest way would be to map `.`, `!` and `?` to automatically add an Enter *every time* you press them, and for you to delete that extra Enter when you *don't* need it.

Comment: I would be able to use line based diffs as @Rich says :)

Comment: @statox @VanLaser Mappings like these would also be an acceptable solution, although I would prefer not having to remove it myself. I suppose I could map `.` and `!` to create a newline and `\.` and `\!` not to create newlines.

Comment: You can probably use the syntax highlighting information to do this. Can you post some LaTeX example where you *do* and *don't* want automatic newlines (I am not that familiar with LaTeX).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which seems to be working *(note the word **seems** I didn't test it extensively so it might not work in some cases)* :

```
function! InsertDot(char)
    " Save the cursor position
    let save_pos=getpos('.')

    " Try to yank inner braces
    call setreg('z', "")
    normal "zyi(
    normal "zyi[
    normal "zyi"
    normal "zyi'

    if ( getreg('z') == "" )
    " If nothing was yanked insert the character and a new line
        execute "normal! i" . a:char . "^M"
        execute "startinsert"
    else
    " If something was yanked insert the dot
    " (messy workaround to get back to the correct position)
        call setpos('.', save_pos)
        execute "normal! i" . a:char
        execute "startinsert"
        let save_pos[2] = save_pos[2]+1
        call setpos('.', save_pos)
    endif
endfunction

inoremap . <c-o>:call InsertDot('.')<CR>
inoremap ! <c-o>:call InsertDot('!')<CR>
```

The characters must be mapped in insert mode to call the function. The function will try to determine if the cursor is between braces and add the character and a new line or only the character accordingly.

Note that the function uses a crappy workaround to preserve the cursor position. I'm pretty sure it can be improved.

---

Otherwise to follow your comment you can use this:

```
inoremap . .^M
inoremap \. .
```

To make <kbd>.</kbd> insert a dot and a new line and <kbd>\ .</kbd> insert only a dot.

---

**Important note**

All the occurences of `^M` in the code must be added with <kbd>CTRL+v</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Both solutions work for me. I tried the latter for a while, but it made it difficult to write "e.g.", "i.e." and so on. I will use `InsertDot()`. Thanks!